# Building & using uWebSockets

Tags: c++, makefile, include, boringssl, uwebsockets

Recently, I've been trying to get [`uWebSockets`](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) working, but I have absolutely no idea how to compile it in order to add it to my project in the include directory. The furthest I've been able to get was through this:

1. Follow the instructions at [the lsquic GitHub](https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic/tree/108c4e7629a8c10b9a73e3d95be0a1652e620fb9) for installing and building both `boringssl` and `lsquic` (Note: I used commit `8927cb8f814ad3cb7cde08f02e826f1eed02bfb0` instead of their example commit for the checkout on `boringssl` as that is the version linked to the version of `uSockets` linked to the latest version of `uWebSockets`)
2. `git clone https://github.com/uNetworking/uSockets.git` and `cd uSockets`

   - Here, I also tried doing `git reset --hard 3cd87094c6dc2e158221a3e25dcefde0b8093ca7` in a separate attempt (the version linked in the latest version of `uWebSockets`) in the `uSockets` directory, but it didn't affect anything to my knowledge.
3. Move the entirety of both `boringssl` and `lsquic`'s contents to `uSockets/boringssl` and `uSockets/lsquic` respectively, and delete the original directories.
4. `cd uSockets` and `WITH_QUIC=1 make examples`

At this point, the `make` fails, with errors such as these:

```bash
examples/http3_client.c: In function ‘on_stream_headers’:
examples/http3_client.c:87:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘us_quic_socket_create_stream’
   87 |     us_quic_socket_create_stream(us_quic_stream_socket(s));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from examples/http3_client.c:11:
src/quic.h:47:6: note: declared here
   47 | void us_quic_socket_create_stream(us_quic_socket_t *s, int ext_size);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are a few more errors, all about functions that have the wrong amount of arguments passed into them.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is this such a big headache, and why is there literally no documentation from `uWebSockets` or `uSockets` on how to actually build their code?

Note: Please add a comment if you would like to see the full logs, I can redo the process and add it to a pastebin.

Comment: I don't understand why you are taking all these steps. I notice that uWebSockets refers to uSockets via a git submodule. Have you tried cloning with `--recurse-submodules` or calling `git submodule update --init --recursive` after a git clone of uWebsockets? I just tried that and a single `make -j8` built everything for me afterwards.

Comment: @Botje I've compiled with that, but now when I try to run the `EchoServer` example and use PostMan to connect to it, it simply gives me a `ECONNREFUSED` error - and on Chrome, it says "This page isn't working - localhost didn't send any data". Any tips? (I also removed the SSL configuration by changing it to `uWS::App()` and still nothing worked)

Comment: However, the `HelloWorld` example does work, so I have no idea what is going wrong with this specific example (and I need WebSockets, not HTTP).